# Swap positions of two nodes in a GraphViz diagram (DOT)

Tags: graphviz, dot

I use the `DOT` language to create a diagram in `R`. As I get a strange result, I am interested how to swap positions of two nodes: node 8 and node c4?

The code:

```
digraph DAG {
    # Initialization of node attributes
    node [shape = box, color = blue]; 2; 3; 4; 

    # Revision to node attributes
    { node [shape = box,style = filled,fillcolor = yellow];  8}

    # Revision to node attributes
    { node [shape = diamond, color = "red"];  c1; c2; c3; c4}

    { rank=same; c1; c2; c3}
    { rank=same; 8; c4}

    # Initialization of edge attributes
    edge [color = green, rel = yields]

    # Edge statements
    2->c1 [headport = w]; 
    c1->c2->c3 
    c2->c1 [tailport = n, headport = n];

    8->c3  [tailport = n, headport = s];
    c3->3  [tailport = e, headport = n]; 
    c3->c2 [tailport = n, headport = n];

    3->c4  [tailport = s, headport = n];
    c4->4  [tailport = s, headport = n];
    c4->8  [tailport = w, headport = e];
}
```

The (incorrect) result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for "wrong way" edges  you may

- swap nodes and use attribute `dir = back` to invert its 'force'
- use attribute `constraint = none` to disable its 'force'

in your case you substitute

```
8->c4  [tailport = e, headport = w, dir = back];
```

by either

```
c4->8  [tailport = w, headport = e, constraint = none];
```

or by

```
8->c4  [tailport = e, headport = w, dir = back];
```